# Order the categories by the number of conferences associated with each category

Tags: php, laravel

Im getting all the categories like:

```
public function index(){
    return view('home')
        ->with('categories', Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get())
        ->with('conferences', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('status','P')->take(8)->get())
}
```

Then in the blade file I show the categories like below. But do you know how to order the categories by the number of conferences associated with each category? That is, show first the categories that have more conferences associated with it. Do you know how that can be achieved?

```
<div class=" d-md-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col p-0 m-0">
                <ul class="Categories__Menu">
                    @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                    <li><a  data-toggle="modal" id="showCategories" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">More <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have relationship setup ?. Like category hasMany conferences and conferences belongsTo category.

Comment: Category model: "class Category extends Model
{
    public function conferences(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conference');
    }
}
"

Comment: Pivot table category_conference:   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_conference', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('conference_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
Category::withCount('conferences')->orderBy('conferences_count', 'desc')->get();
```